# Are there genAIs which can quickly generate diverse images for foreign language speaking practice without prompting?

Tags: image-generation, recommendation

For practicing Chinese, I record YouTube videos of me speaking.  I'd thus be interested in a genAI which can quickly generate a large number (say 100) of diverse images for me to describe in Chinese (such as the following [I forget which AI generated this]):

> [image: an old man sitting on a bench on a sunny day, reading a book]

For language practice, you can usually do two things: (a) describe literally what's in the image ("there's an old man sitting on a bench..."), or (b) make up a story related to what's in the image ("Every Saturday, Greg goes to the local park...").  Imagine me flicking through 100 different images, and describing them in Chinese out loud, while recording a video.

So I'm looking for a tool where...

- I'll be able to push a button, and a new image appears on the screen.  I don't want to type in a written prompt.  I'm thinking along the lines of [ThisPersonDoesNotExist.com](https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/) or [100,000 humans that don't exist](https://generated.photos/humans), but with more diverse images than human faces or bodies.
- The images don't need to be high-quality (in fact, it's better if they're low quality---a black and white cartoon may be a good choice); a typical example for language practice is:

  > [image: A black-and-white cartoon of a girl bringing her mother (who is sitting on a couch) a slice of cake; it's title is 妈妈辛苦了 "Mother is exhausted"]

  sourced from [Kantuxiehua.cn](http://www.kantuxiehua.cn/yinianji/80.html).
- It needs to be generated almost instantly so I'm not wasting time in my video.  If an individual image is not a good choice, I should be able to quickly generate another.
- The image needs to be "describable" in words, so not just an abstract blue blur or something.
- The images should be family friendly, like a woman going for a jog with her dog, not in-progress medical procedures.

(A paid service is not in my budget, but I'd still be interested in such answers out of academic curiosity.)

**Question**: Are there genAIs which can quickly generate diverse images for foreign language speaking practice without prompting?

I'm also open to alternatives for how to achieve my goal, e.g., a genAI which can give me a .zip of 100 diverse images, where I don't need to generate them while recording.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there genAIs which can quickly generate diverse images for foreign language speaking practice without prompting?

Generating images without prompting is called [unconditional image generation](https://huggingface.co/tasks/unconditional-image-generation). Otherwise, one could generate some random text and feed it as a prompt.

> I'll be able to push a button, and a new image appears on the screen.

Aside from using an unconditional image generation model, one could use a synthetic image dataset.

Comment: Specifically, I might recommend this feature of this extension for Auto1111's Stable Diffusion webui: https://github.com/adieyal/sd-dynamic-prompts#im-feeling-lucky

Answer (score 1):

[Leonardo.AI](https://app.leonardo.ai/ai-generations) has a "New Random Prompt" button (the dice on the left):

> [image: an example of Leonardo.AI generating a random prompt]

This generates random images:

> [image: screenshot of Leonardo.AI's results for the above random prompt; it's quite surreal]

---

I've also found I can ask genAI:

> Can you give me 5 random nouns, verbs, and adjectives?

> Nouns: book, chair, dog, car, tree
> Verbs: run, dance, sing, sleep, eat
> Adjectives: happy, tall, blue, sleepy, delicious

And just copy/paste the result into Leonardo.AI:

> [image: Leonardo.AI results for generating images using random words]